# Deploy ADF from prod to dev

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I currently have Azure Data Factory on Prod. It is already functional and has pipelines, Linked Services etc.

Now I want to deploy Develop, have built Deplyoment pipelines and am able to move Prod to Dev.

However, I need to make a few changes to make Dev work, e.g. I need to adjust parameters of Linked Service so that it accesses storage/KV on Dev and not on Prod.

But if I have developed later on Dev (e.g. new pipeline) and want to move these changes to Prod, of course the parameters of Linked Service are also deployed with PR on prod.

This means that I then have Linked Service on both Dev and Prod and both access Dev.

Example:

```
PR Dev to Prod, wants to change - https://prdtestkv.vault.azure.net --> https://devtestkv.vault.azure.net

Then Prod linked service KV is the same as on Dev --> https://devtestkv.vault.azure.net
```

is it possible to exclude these changes during PR from Dev to Prod? So that I can only merge other changes? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @gio.s, is the answer below to parameterize the database name and powershell scripts to replace the strings helps you? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to different databases on the same logical SQL server, you can parameterize the database name in the linked service definition. You can parameterize a linked service and pass dynamic values at run time. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services?tabs=data-factory) for more information. Here are the [Supported linked service types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services?tabs=data-factory#supported-linked-service-types)

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell scripts to replace the strings while deploying to or from one env to another :

```
(Get-Content -path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_adfrepo/annu-analytics/TemplateForWorkspace.json) -replace 'https://prdtestkv.vault.azure.net','https://devtestkv.vault.azure.net'| Set-Content -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_adfrepo/annu-analytics/TemplateForWorkspace.json
```

Just change the order of prod and dev kv connection string while deploying from  dev to prod.